# como mostrar graficamente a relacao entre duas colunas de um dataframe usando uma terceira?

Tags: python

em python tenho um dataframe(df) com varias colunas, e estou a tentar descobrir se existe alguma relacao entre a coluna "Happiness Score" (float) e a coluna "Generosity" (float), mas tenho de mostrar isso graficamente atraves de uma outra coluna "Freedom" (float).

tentei fazer:

(
ggplot(df)+
geom_point(aes(x="Happiness Score",y="Generosity",
fill="Happiness Score"))
+geom_smooth(
aes(x="Happiness Score",y="Generosity")
)
+labs(title="relación la felicidad con la generosidad ",
x="Happiness Score",
y="Generosity")
)

mas obviamente que sö me relaciona duas variaveis, o que nao pretendo.

alguma sugestao?
obrigada

Answer (score 0):

### Função corr do pandas

Esse função calcula a correlação entre as colunas de um df

```py
pd[["Happiness Score", "Generosity"]].corr()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

### Mapa de calor do Seaborn

A biblioteca searborn tem um gráfico que pode ser usado para demonstrar a correlação entre colunas de um df

https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/spreadsheet_heatmap.html

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).